# How do you add thickness to a circle mesh?

Tags: modeling

I made a mesh circle now I want to add some thickness to it so it looks like a wire or string, not rope.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Try adding more words :)

Answer (score 1):

A mesh>circle has no faces, so it is not renderable.

Also, without any faces it cannot be used with the solidify modifier to give thickness.

You might want to use a curve>cirlce instead, so that you can control the thickness with the bevel setting.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out by watching this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b3Se__j6iI.

Comment: This is what I do, "circle", "alt +c" - curve from mesh, modifier = subdivision surface, curve object data - fill = full - depth = 0.020.